# No longer working with Telly Visuals plugin for virtual

Tags: pushbullet

Any ideas how to get a no longer supported third party windows app to work with pushbullet again? I gather with pushbullet updates the API no longer speaks to Telly Visuals. Unfortunately the creator of Telly Visuals is no longer supporting it. I have a very outdated knowledge of coding but want to have a go at updating Telly Visuals so it will again work with pushbullet. Any offers of help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried to update the access token with no luck.

Comment: Hi Brian I noticed you edited my post many thanks. Do you happen to have any idea on how to get an outdated unsupported software to work with pushbullet updated API and can offer any help? There is a large community that used to use this software but no longer can because the guy who created has disappeared (we think due to ill health). The software is called telly visuals and was used by DJ's to be to display sms and WhatsApp messages that were pushed from pushbullet. The software allowed the user to edit how the messages were viewed by the audience on tv screens. Any help would be great